# What are real world examples of when Linked Lists should be used?

Tags: c#, java, data-structures, linked-list

Another programmer was mentioning that they haven't found a use case for using a linked list data structure in any professional software in his career.  I couldn't think of any good examples off the top of my head.  He is mostly a C# and Java developer

Can anyone give some examples where this was the correct data structure to solve a particular real world problem?

**Related:** [What is a practical, real world example of the Linked List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644167/)

Comment: If you actually read both questions, it isn't a dupe at all.  The related question wants a real-world analogy to a linked list, this question wants real world examples of using one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A real-world example would be a FIFO queue. An simple array-based list is pretty bad for that because you need to add at one end and remove at the other end, and one of those operations will be O(n) with an array-based list (unless you add extra logic to work with a start AND end index), while both are O(1) with a linked list without extra effort.

Comment: Array-based FIFO queues usually have O(1) queue and dequeue operations. The only time one of them needs to be O(n) is when it grows/resizes. Also, array-based queues have some advantages over linked-list based queues such as requiring less space and not fragmenting the data.

Comment: I should say *sometimes* requiring less space. Depends on things like how full the array is and how big the linked list's node pointer/index is.

Comment: Hm, I suppose one could save a start and end index to make both operations O(1), but that would require extra effort. Will rewrite my answer to relect that.

Comment: Then again, e.g. C# has a Queue class. I'd rather use that, wouldn't I?

Comment: I agree with @flq -- this really does not stand the counter-argument "why not just use queues instead". I don't think it answers the question.

Answer (score 29):

Linked Lists offer several advantages over comparable data structures such as static or dynamically expanding arrays.

1. LinkedLists does not require contiguous blocks of memory and therefore **can** help reduce memory fragmentation
2. LinkedLists support efficient removal of elements (dynamic arrays usually force a shift in all of the elements).
3. LinkedLists support efficient addition of elements (dynamic arrays can cause a re-allocation + copy, if a particular add exceeds the current capacity)

Any place where these advantages would be significantly valuable to a program (and the disadvantages of a LinkedList were negligible) would be a place to use a LinkedList.

Comment: Removal of elements ussually involve searching for them first - an action linked lists suck at :)

Comment: @Meeh, Yes, if you don't already have the element you must search.  That's one of the disadvantages.  In some cases though, you may already have the node you want to delete and hence it's more efficient.

Comment: True that - just wanted to point it out. No data-structure is pure heaven, sadly :(

Comment: Regarding point #1, memory pools help tremendously with that.  =)  Node sizes are usually fixed in a linked list.

Comment: So the answer seems to be it's about memory allocation and the efficient *implementation* of abstract tools, which explains why a C#/Java programmer wouldn't grok the difference.

Comment: @Meeh: There are lots of variations of linked lists, such as skip lists, which improve their lookup time. Self-balancing binary trees, for example, can be implemented as linked lists where each node points to two others nodes. AVL trees and skip lists both support efficient O(log n) lookups.

Comment: Don't mean to knock you, but listing its advantages and saying to use it when you want those advantages isn't specific enough to be examples. The guy's asking for real-world examples.

Comment: @Chris, @Andreas, true these are not specific examples.  I chose to go with scenarios vs. examples because it's applicable to a wider audience. I can give an example of where I've used a linked list in the past but it's unlikely to be relevant to anyone reading.  Instead I called out the reasons

Comment: @Jared if it isn't a secret I'd love to hear about the example. Sometimes it's good to do the extrapolation yourself.

Answer (score 17):

Intrusive linked lists are interesting beasts for game development.  For example, it's somewhat common practice to have an intrusive singly- or doubly-linked "render" list:

```
class Renderable /* or class Object, whatever */
{
  // ...
  Renderable * m_pNext;
  Renderable * m_pPrev; // or not, if singly-linked
  // ...
}
```

As Renderables come into and out of existence they can register themselves with this list -- without causing any memory allocation.  If their render depth or priority is changed they can remove and reinsert themselves, etc.

When it comes time to render, all you need to do is find the head of the list and zip through, calling the appropriate method!

(There are, of course, many variations on this theme, with multiple separate lists, etc.  And you don't need to have an intrusive list to make this work, I just find the intrusive ones interesting.)

Comment: I wish I could favourite an answer.  =]

Answer (score 16):

Linked Lists ([paired with a hashtable](http://github.com/sambo99/media-library/blob/d659cb42a48ba3f77c68a9fa695b96f22310be4a/MediaLibrary/Caching/IndexedLinkedList.cs)) are really useful for [LRU Caches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589301/17174).

Every Get needs to bump a node to the front of the list, an operation that is really cheap with linked lists.

Answer (score 14):

**Some example of single linked list.**

1. Undo button of any application like Microsoft Word, Paint, etc: A linked list of states.
2. GPS Navigation: A linked list of map data. Travelling from origin to destination is example of traversing through all nodes. Rerouting
   by a GPS is an example of Add and Remove operations of map data.

**Some example of double linked list.**

1. Browser's Next and Previous Button: a linked list of URLs.
2. Image Viewer's Next and Previous Button: a linked list of images
3. Undo and Redo button of Photoshop, a linked list of states.

Answer (score 8):

Stacks and queues are very clear examples of linked lists, but as other already have mentioned them I'd like to add a few other examples:

DOM stores nodes as linked lists. A simple javascript sample that is really the same in any language:

```
for (var node = parent.firstChild; node != null; node = node.nextSibling) {
    // ..
}
```

I would imagine that a java developer has come across XML at some point.

Trees are another good examples of linked lists, even though they aren't simple one dimensional ones. Someone who's done a lot of java development has probably come across TreeMaps and TreeSets.

The entire discussion seems a bit silly to me. Linked lists are a fundamental data structure that is used everywhere. The only reason that one might think that he/she hasn't come across them is that you don't really have to worry about the implementation of data structures in todays high level languages, but of course they're still there.

Answer (score 6):

They occur all the time, anywhere an object has a property that points to another object of the same type. In the CLR, exceptions form a linked list, due to the `InnerException` property.

Answer (score 5):

An *immutable* linked list is a very valuable structure, since you can 'share structure' with other lists with the same tail.  Most functional languages include an immutable linked list type as one of their fundamental data structures, and these types are used all over the place.

Comment: Isn't sharing parts of the data structure also possible with arrays?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a BIOS extension (basically a device driver for a BIOS, written in assembly) for a USB host controller.  -- Implementing a high-level seemingly abstract data structure like a linked list in assembly isn't as hard as it sounds. --  The controller serviced I/O requests for keyboard and disk using a linked list of packets in main memory.  I maintained a pool of free packets in another linked list.  Performing I/O basically involved grabbing a free packet from the beginning of the free list, configuring the packet, adding the packet to the device's list, and re-adding the packet to the beginning of the free pool when the I/O finished.  Linked lists are lightning fast for moving around objects like this, especially when the objects are large, since the objects don't actually have to move.  Only their pointers need to be updated.

An array-based queue would have required:

- using a begin/end index pointer, which is fast but requires fixing the size of the queue so that the producer has to wait when the consumer's queue is full and locking the queue while the whole packet is filled if there is more than one producer
- shifting all the elements in the queue whenever you insert/remove, which is slow for large objects

So, linked lists are a nice way to implement an arbitrarily long first-in-first-out queue of large objects.

Another thing to be careful about is that for small objects or where you allocate objects from a conventional heap instead of a custom free pool, arrays can be faster because copying isn't really that slow if it's not done that often, and the repeated allocation from the heap that a linked list would require every time a new element is added is slow.

Of course, you may want to simulate and measure your particular scenario with some throwaway test code to find the answer.  I like to run loops a few million times with linked lists and arrays, with small and large objects, and time how long each takes in real time.  Sometimes you'll be surprised.

Answer (score 3):

As perhaps the best real world example in .Net consider the [MultiCastDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188792.aspx).

Linked lists implemented in this way, where the list chaining aspect is backed directly into the type rather than as a separate container, can be extremely powerful and efficient. They come however with a variety of trade offs.
One obvious one is code duplication, you must bake this logic in each type. Techniques such as extending a base class providing the pointer are messy (you lose strong typing without generics) and often unacceptable from a performance point of view.
Another is that you are limited to one implementation per type. You cannot make a singly linked structure into a doubly linked one without inserting an extra field in every instance and updating all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

As said already linked lists are very useful when you need to insert and delete elements.

For example to help debug memory management in my code I recently implemeneted a link list between all my refrence counted objects so that at the end of the program (when the refrences should all have hit zero and deleted the objects) I could see exactly what was still left, useually resulting in me being able to find a single object at the root of the problem.

CPython implements something similir with a massive linked list between nearly every when its built with debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to the tag 'Data Structures', at a low level such as assembly, linked lists are an ideal way to store variable length lists of other data structures.  There is no overhead for maintaining the list length or end, and there no is need for fixed size list items.  The last reason also applies to higher level languages.

Answer (score 2):

Linked list is the essential data structure for [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links), which is the technique used to efficiently implement [Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_X), which is a backtracking algorithm to find all solutions to the NP-complete [exact cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem, to which many hard problems are naturally reducible to.

Answer (score 1):

Stacks and Queues are examples of linked lists.

Comment: Stacks and queues *can* be implemented using linked lists. .NET stacks and queues are arrays, however.

Comment: The BCL implementation of both use an array.

Answer (score 1):

As daustin777 points out, linked lists are all around you and you may not even know it.  But the practicality of the matter is that they allow for some pretty basic operations to be performed with relative ease and flexibility.  For example, not to sort, just swap pointers around.  Need to insert or remove at arbitrary places?  Insert or remove your pointers within the list.  Need to iterate forwards and backwards ... linked list.  While not precisely a business example, I hope this clarifies it enough for you to apply it to your own real world business case.

Answer (score 1):

If I may answer this question in a slightly different manner than others have, lately I've been using linked lists to organize music lists. The lists provide an excellent way to store and sort through music by artist, song, album, even ratings or song length. Mine is a doubly linked list, but I could see it being applicable with a singly linked list as well. Shopping lists would fit as well, and if you're OCD like my mom, you can easily organize it be aisle and frozen foods last!

If we include stacks and queues, the obvious for queues is a print queue or a music playlist (lists in any sense are good obviously).

Answer (score 0):

For problems where the number of maximal nodes are constrained to 100 or below or so, linked lists are a reasonable solution. The same can be true of things like bubble sort and other things that are thought to be sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Linked list implementation spotted in the wild:

[Python's LRU cache](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L525):

```py
...
...
    cache_get = cache.get    # bound method to lookup a key or return None
    cache_len = cache.__len__  # get cache size without calling len()
    lock = RLock()           # because linkedlist updates aren't threadsafe
    root = []                # root of the circular doubly linked list
...
...
```

Yet notice that the `_lru_cache_wrapper` function is actually [imported](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L641) from the `C module` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L737):

```
...
...
typedef struct lru_list_elem {
    PyObject_HEAD
    struct lru_list_elem *prev, *next;  /* borrowed links */
    Py_hash_t hash;
    PyObject *key, *result;
} lru_list_elem;
...
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Linked list pros:

- Dynamic storage nullifies fragmentation
- Fast insertion / removal
- Fast access to first element (and end if implemented bidirectional)
- Efficient memory usage

Linked list cons:

- Slow traversing

Out of my head, I'd implement stacks, queues and messagepumps using linked lists. I'd also implement a datatree using multi-reference linked-lists for fast insertion / removal.

Comment: Several of your "pros" are cons because array-based lists are better