# Fastest way to move a part of an array to the right

Tags: .net, performance, arrays

I need to "insert" an element at the given index in a small array. That is, to move all elements with greater indices 1 place to the right. What is the fastest way to do that in .NET?

NOTE: I added my own answer, but I am still looking for an explanation and faster alternatives.

EDIT: I do need an array, not a `List<T>` and not a linked list.

UPDATE: Since I didn't get an explanation of strange performance results, I've asked that question separately: [Why is copying references to strings much slower than copying ints (but vice versa for Array.Copy())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279407/why-does-copying-elements-one-by-one-outperform-array-copy-for-a-small-array-of)

Answer (score 4):

There are two obvious approaches: use `Array.Copy` and copy elements one by one:

```
private static void ElementByElement<T>(T[] arg, int start) {
    for (int i = arg.Length - 1; i > start; i--) {
        arg[i] = arg[i - 1];
    }
}

private static T BuiltInCopy<T>(T[] arg, int start) {
    Array.Copy(arg, start, arg, start + 1, arg.Length - start - 1);
    return arg[0];            
}
```

On one hand, `List<T>` insert uses `Array.Copy`. On the other, `Array.Copy` is non-generic and can do a *lot* of extra work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx

I expected `Array.Copy` to be faster. However, the results of this MiniBench test surprised me.

```
internal class Program {
    private static int smallArraySize = 32;

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        BenchArrayCopy();
    }

    private static void BenchArrayCopy() {
        var smallArrayInt = new int[smallArraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < smallArraySize; i++)
            smallArrayInt[i] = i;

        var smallArrayString = new string[smallArraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < smallArraySize; i++)
            smallArrayString[i] = i.ToString();

        var smallArrayDateTime = new DateTime[smallArraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < smallArraySize; i++)
            smallArrayDateTime[i] = DateTime.Now;

        var moveInt = new TestSuite<int[], int>("Move part of array right by 1: int")
            .Plus(BuiltInCopy, "Array.Copy()")
            .Plus(ElementByElement, "Element by element in a for loop")
            .RunTests(smallArrayInt, 0);

        var moveString = new TestSuite<string[], string>("Move part of array right by 1: string")
            .Plus(BuiltInCopy, "Array.Copy()")
            .Plus(ElementByElement, "Element by element in a for loop")
            .RunTests(smallArrayString, "0");

        var moveDT = new TestSuite<DateTime[], DateTime>("Move part of array right by 1: DateTime")
            .Plus(BuiltInCopy, "Array.Copy()")
            .Plus(ElementByElement, "Element by element in a for loop")
            .RunTests(smallArrayDateTime, smallArrayDateTime[0]);

        moveInt.Display(ResultColumns.All, moveInt.FindBest());
        moveString.Display(ResultColumns.All, moveInt.FindBest());
        moveDT.Display(ResultColumns.All, moveInt.FindBest());
    }

    private static T ElementByElement<T>(T[] arg) {
        int start = 8;
        for (int i = smallArraySize - 1; i > start; i--) {
            arg[i] = arg[i - 1];
        }
        return arg[0];
    }

    private static T BuiltInCopy<T>(T[] arg) {
        int start = 8;
        int length = smallArraySize - start - 1;
        Array.Copy(arg, start, arg, start + 1, length);
        return arg[0];            
    }
}
```

Here are the results from two runs:

```
f:\MyProgramming\TimSort\Benchmarks\bin\Release>Benchmarks.exe
============ Move part of array right by 1: int ============
Array.Copy()                     568475865 0:31.606 1,73
Element by element in a for loop 980013061 0:31.449 1,00

============ Move part of array right by 1: string ============
Array.Copy()                     478224336 0:31.618 2,06
Element by element in a for loop 220168237 0:30.926 4,38

============ Move part of array right by 1: DateTime ============
Array.Copy()                     382906030 0:27.870 2,27
Element by element in a for loop 458265102 0:29.239 1,99


f:\MyProgramming\TimSort\Benchmarks\bin\Release>Benchmarks.exe
============ Move part of array right by 1: int ============
Array.Copy()                     500925013 0:28.514 1,76
Element by element in a for loop 988394220 0:31.967 1,00

============ Move part of array right by 1: string ============
Array.Copy()                     483178262 0:30.048 1,92
Element by element in a for loop 193092931 0:27.642 4,43

============ Move part of array right by 1: DateTime ============
Array.Copy()                     450569361 0:30.807 2,11
Element by element in a for loop 568054290 0:31.385 1,71
```

That is, for `int` and `DateTime` `ElementByElement` is significantly faster; while for `string` `BuiltInCopy` is over twice as fast as `ElementByElement` (and twice as slow as `ElementByElement` for `int`). I'd expect the results for `int` and `string` to be very similar on a 32-bit machine, since a reference to `string` on the stack is the same size as an `int` and no operations other than reading and writing stack memory should be involved.

Comment: maybe there's a lot of boxing going on? (the arrays using a value-type are slower than those using a reference type...)

Comment: In this case I'd expect `Array.Copy` on `int` to be slower than `string`, which it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using a `linked list` would be better in this case.

Comment: Except when he still needs random access

Comment: You can access an arbitrary element in a linked list albeit takes a bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

First I would question whether an array is an appropriate data structure choice given this requirement. However, I can see a possible optimisation in your 'element by element' copying code:

```
    private static void ElementByElement2<T>(T[] arg, int start)
    {
        int i = arg.Length - 1;
        while (i > start)
            arg[i] = arg[--i];
    }
```

I have benchmarked this and is approximately twice as fast as your for-loop solution.

Comment: The OP said a small array.  Its going to be hard to beat a linear copy inside 1-2 cache lines.

Comment: I get very different results from my benchmark: it's indistinguishable on `int` (1,01 vs 1,00), slightly faster on strings (4,11 vs 4,20), and slightly slower on DateTime (2,00 vs 1,70).

Comment: YMMV. On my machine it is consistently faster (Intel Xeon E7730, .Net 3.5 SP1). I'm just benchmarking an int array.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `List<T>` as an example - it uses `Array.Copy`, suggesting that **if you are constrained to using an array**, then this might indeed be your best option.

Or, as Indeera notes - use a different container! Depending on the exact usage, some options

- if you are *always* inserting at 0, use a `List<T>` (or keep your own array with spare capacity, but I can't think *why*), but think of it backwards - so "insert" becomes "append", which is cheaper (especially if you don't have to reallocate)
- linked list is an option
- as is a queue / stack (depending on if/how you remove data)
- or for both prepend and append, keep an array with spare capacity on *both* sides, wrapped in something like (but more complex than) a `List<T>` - and maintain the offset - i.e. you have an array of 100, and know that your "zero" is 50, and you've used 20; insert at "zero" is then simple changes the value at offset 49, decrements the main zero offset to 49 and increments the virtual length to 21

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to a given index, you should be using a Linked list. See also: [What are real world examples of when Linked Lists should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670104/what-are-real-world-examples-of-when-linked-lists-should-be-used)